# nested lists converting certain elements into ints

Tags: python-3.x

I've imported a file with tabular data and have made it a nested list. I would like to convert numerical string elements to inergers. how do i convert them to the ints ?
this is what i have thus far:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
prov_data = []

for line in f:
    prov_data.append(line.strip().split(","))
    prov = []
    for prov in prov_data:
        for prov in range(len(prov_data)):
            prov.append(prov_data[prov])

f.close()
```

The list is:

```
l = [['MB' '1281000' '14'], ['NB' '754900' '14'] ,['NL' '528300' '7'],['NT' '43900' '1']]
```

basically im trying to understand how to convert those second and third elements

Comment: `[[int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for y in x] for x in l]`?

Answer (score 0):

Just convert them after the split

```
def convert_to_int(foo):
    try:
        return int(foo.strip())
    except ValueError:
        return foo
...
prov_data = [ [convert_to_int(x) for x in line.strip().split(",")]
              for line in f
            ]
...
```